# trigger a gulp task from c# code running on azure server

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, gulp, runtime

I have a gulpfile which is compiled on the local machine before deployment.
The website is hosted in azure.

I am looking to have a handler in c# code that will run the gulp task on the server everytime a button on the website is pressed.

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the gulp task do when the button is pressed?

Comment: compiles css at runtime

Comment: it reads values from a cms at runtime changing less variables, hence why need css to be re-compiled on the fly